# SingleEmailMessage getting into SPAM folder

Tags: apex, email, email-template

I'm sending an email with a Messaging.SingleEmailMessage using a verified Org Wide Email Address.

Also, I have Enable compliance with standard email security mechanisms and Enable Sender ID compliance but I'm still getting these emails in the SPAM folder.

The mail contains an Email Template (text) with one line of text and {Custom_Object__c.Link}

Gmail and Hotmail get it to the SPAM folder and the next warning

> "Be careful with this message GMail could not verify that it actually
>   came from xxxxxx.com. Avoid clicking links, downloading attachments,
>   or replying with personal information."

Does anyone know if I'm missing something?

Comment: Have you followed [these directions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=emailadmin_send_from_salesforce_improve_deliverability.htm&type=5)? Particularly, have you configured DKIM keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was missing the email relay.